# how to build docker image by docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
web:
  build: .
  context: ./
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  container_name: demo
  volumes:
    - .:/images
```

I got an error:

> ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
>   Unsupported config option for services.web: 'dockerfile'

So I would like to build the container and also run. I will have a few more containers to build and run. Is it possible by docker-compose?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `dockerfile` option? Since the error clearly says this shouldn't be there

Comment: You don't need `context:` or `dockerfile:` here.  If you kept them, they need to be indented one step more and you need to remove the context directory name from the `build:` line.

Comment: @FrancescoGimignano I have to build the container. Without those how can I build?

Comment: @DavidMaze could tell more what do u mean by emove the context directory name from the build:

Comment: have you checked the docker version> 1.13.0+

Comment: indentation also matters https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

Comment: You need `build: .`, or `build: { context: . }`, but not both.

Comment: @DavidMaze seems indentation issue, I don't think braces are required as per [compose-reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken the issue is after `build` you have a dot, the `dockerfile` and `context` are not correct idented. And I think the bar in the `context` should not be there.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  api:
    image: image-name
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: path/to/Dockerfile
    container_name: container-name
```

I think this resolves the issue you have, but couldn't test it.

Comment: Can u pls share the whole yml. Coz, I am confused under which level the build: will be

Comment: I completed more the file

Comment: ERROR: Version in "./docker-compose.yml" is unsupported. But if I add version: "2" . It works fine.

Comment: that configuration works for me with the docker-compose version 1.22.0

Comment: main docker-compose version 1.17.1, build unknown on ubuntu 18

Answer (score 0):

You need to respect the indentations , here is an example for building Nginx docker image https://github.com/wshihadeh/three_methods_to_share_assets/blob/master/precompile_during_docker_build/docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: server
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

Answer (score 0):

YAML files works on indentation and an indentation error marks the yaml as invalid. Always validate your yaml in appropriate linting tool for e.g. https://www.yamllint.com/

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  web:
    image: my-web-service
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    ports:
      - '9080:8080'
```

`context value is .` because my Dockerfile and docker-compose.yaml files exists at the same location